Why does the TSP in NetworkX not return the shortest path?
I'm trying to use NetworkX's traveling_salesman_problem to find the shortest path between nodes, but it seems to return a longer path than is necessary. Here's a minimal example:
import shapely
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a 10x10 grid

vert = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString([[(x, 0), (x, 100)] for x in range(0, 110, 10)])
hori = shapely.affinity.rotate(vert, 90)
grid = shapely.unary_union([vert, hori])

# Turn it into a graph

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([(*line.coords, {"distance": line.length}) for line in grid.geoms])

# Select nodes and visit them via TSP and manually

nodes = [(20., 20.), (30., 30.), (20., 80.), (80., 20.), (50., 50.), (60., 10.), (40., 40.), (50., 40.), (50, 30)]

tsp_path = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem(
    graph,
    weight="distance",
    nodes=nodes,
    cycle=False,
    method=nx.approximation.christofides
)

tsp_path = shapely.geometry.LineString(tsp_path)

manual_path = shapely.geometry.LineString([(20, 80), (50, 80), (50, 30), (40, 30), (40, 40), (40, 30), (20, 30), (20, 20), (60, 20), (60, 10), (60, 20), (80, 20)])

# Plot results

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), sharey=True)

for ax in axes:
    for line in grid.geoms:
        ax.plot(*line.xy, c="k", lw=.25)
    ax.scatter(*zip(*nodes), c="k")
    ax.set_aspect("equal")
axes[0].plot(*tsp_path.xy, c="b")
axes[0].set_title(f"TSP solution length={tsp_path.length}")
axes[1].plot(*manual_path.xy, c="r")
axes[1].set_title(f"manual length={manual_path.length}")

What am I missing? Is the TSP the wrong algorithm for this?

Edit to return to origin:
If I run traveling_salesman_problem with cycle=True to make the route return to the origin node, and change my manual route to:
manual_path = shapely.geometry.LineString([(20, 80), (50, 80), (50, 30), (40, 30), (40, 40), (40, 30), (20, 30), (20, 20), (60, 20), (60, 10), (60, 20), (80, 20), (80, 80), (20, 80)])

I get the (longer) below left from NetworkX and the (shorter) below right for my manual route:


From Wikipedia: 'the travelling salesman problem (TSP) asks the following question: "Given a list of cities and the distances between each pair of cities, what is the shortest possible route that visits each city exactly once and returns to the origin city?"'.  That's the problem that the TSP algorithm is designed to solve.  I don't think that is the problem that you are trying to solve, and I'm pretty sure that neither plot represents a valid solution to the particular TSP that you setup in the line nodes = ...

Thanks. I've edited the Q to show the effect of returning to the origin point. I still get a very long route from NetworkX, so must be missing something else.

networkx only provides you with approximation, it's in the name of the package itself, so there is no guarantee you will get the optimal TSP solution.

I consistently get shorter paths when the weight parameter is named weight:
import shapely
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make a 10x10 grid

vert = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString([[(x, 0), (x, 100)] for x in range(0, 110, 10)])
hori = shapely.affinity.rotate(vert, 90)
grid = shapely.unary_union([vert, hori])

params = ["weight", "distance"]
paths = []

for param in params:

    # Turn it into a graph

    graph = nx.Graph()
    graph.add_edges_from([(*line.coords, {param: line.length}) for line in grid.geoms])
    
    # Select nodes and visit them via TSP
    
    nodes = [(20., 20.), (30., 30.), (20., 80.), (80., 20.), (50., 50.), (60., 10.), (40., 40.), (50., 40.), (50, 30)]
    
    path = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem(
        graph,
        weight=param,
        nodes=nodes,
        cycle=False,
        method=nx.approximation.christofides
    )
    
    paths.append(shapely.geometry.LineString(path))

# Plot results

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5), sharey=True)

for ax, param, path, c in zip(axes, params, paths, ["b", "r"]):
    for line in grid.geoms:
        ax.plot(*line.xy, c="k", lw=.25)
    ax.scatter(*zip(*nodes), c="k")
    ax.plot(*path.xy, c=c)
    ax.set_title(f"Param={param}, length={path.length}")
    ax.set_aspect("equal")


or with cycle=True:

So it looks a bit like a bug to me at the moment.

Confirmed as a bug: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/7720
